# Documentation for getting Facebook feed stream on website?

Tags: html, facebook, web, facebook-timeline

Trying to integrate a Facebook page stream into an element for a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) has a "show stream" option that displays this data.

Comment: I do not seem to get this to work for me. I do copy the cope exactly as instructed. Still, my browser does not show anything. (It's just blank..) Anyone had a problem with this and know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, it is against Facebook's policy to exactly copy any of it's features and use on your own site (as if emulating Facebook).

With that said, you need to grab this information manually using either the Graph API or FQL. There is no social plugin that can do this automatically.

You can check out the Graph API documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

You can test out some Graph API calls here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

You can learn more about FQL here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post, but can I ask you please, what do you mean it is 'against the rules of facebook to copy any of it's features and use on your own site'? I am currently writing php script to integrate facebook newsfeed into my website with the JSON object that is returned from facebook. I am displaying posts in a similar way as they are displayed on facebook, with links back to facebook if required... Is this against the rules? thanks